# What's a RESTful way of presenting a form?

Tags: web-services, rest

I understand most of how a RESTful site design should function, but in implementing a blog cannot decide the best way to present the form to insert a new blog post. Would example.com/posts/create be reasonable? This feels like the "create" is not restful, like it's putting information into the URI that should be simply represented by PUT/POST.

How would others do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) for the Rails view on this.

```
Verb   URL            Controller  Action   Used For
GET    /photos/new    Photos      new      return an HTML form for creating a new photo
POST   /photos        Photos      create   create a new photo
```

So, in your situation, GET `/posts/new` to get the new post form, but POST `/posts` to create a new post.

The point is, you're POSTing a new blog post, but to do that you need to GET the form that will enable you to do this. In a way, the new blog post form is just another (static) resource.

Comment: That's where my mind was leading but it's reassuring to see other people agree :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like the way that URL feels, then change it to:

```
GET http://example.com/posts/createform
```

Comment: I think this hits the nail on the head.  You just changed the verb `create` for the noun `createform`. Indeed, just `/posts/form` works well too, I guess.  But please remember to allow clients to discover the URI of the form somewhere else!

Answer (score 0):

Use a POST to submit the information for the insert, and then have the page do a redirect to the with the new ID in the URL.  You don't want to have the new information on the URL since a user refreshing the URL will post twice.

Comment: Yes, but what about displaying the form for inserting the new post? That's what the question is about.